# React Native - can I set dynamic initial state?

Tags: react-native

let say I have a state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    FirstTime:
    {
      foo: 'ex1'
    }
  }
}
```

and then I `setState` the `FirstTime` to add another key/value:

```
this.setState({FirstTime: {...this.state.FirstTime, bar: 'ex2'}})
```

there's a way to change the initial state to be like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    FirstTime:
    {
      foo: 'ex1',
      bar: 'ex2'
    }
  }
}
```

when I reloaded the apps?

Comment: Make another object and push the data into state in getDerivedStateToProps / componentDidMount method

Comment: @RaajNadar does it mean like i need to put `setState` on `componentDidMount`? it will remove the `dynamic` i thought

Comment: if you will give me more info about what you are trying to achieve I Can give to alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      FirstTime: {
        foo: 'ex1'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.FirstTime); //Sorry a typo found in this line
    return (
      <div>Hey</div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let obj = {
      bar: 'ex2'
    }

    let finalData = { ...this.state.FirstTime, ...obj }
    
    this.setState({ FirstTime: finalData })
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It should do the trick, but if i add `console.log(this.state.FirstTime)` at the beginning of `componentDidMount()` the FirstTime still have one key, it's not what i want

Comment: i told you, that's just a trick to makes `FirstTime` has 2 key while rendering, but the `FirstTime` in constructor will *__Always__* get 1 `key`, because the `constructor` running once!

Comment: Use high order components then bcuz constructor is the thing that runs first we can't do anything before constructor!